# Software to convert an APK file into native code

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I am converting an existing desktop application to an Android application, but I am very worried about reverse engineering and stuff like that. For the desktop application, I use Launch4J, but I am unaware of anything that can turn an [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file into native code on Android.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: Not an answer (I'm not a dev), but some keywords: Native code is rather rare on Android, but there's the "NDK". For code protection, most devs I've heard using any spoke of something called "ProGuard". Others simply make their code Open Source – which also minimizes the danger of "reverse engineering" ;)

Comment: You can't protect your app from [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [android-apktool - A tool for reverse engineering Android APK files](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/).

---

Some useful resources:

- [Apktool v1.4.3 - a tool for reverse engineering APK files - On XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=640592)
- [Decompile, Edit, and Recompile in One Tool with APK Studio](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/decompile-edit-and-recompile-in-one-tool-with-apk-studio/)

*NOTE: I would recommend visiting **http://www.xda-developers.com/** for more Android development needs*.